# How to check how much strings are similar in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have to check how much for instance:

`caffe` and `latte` is alike, so `a` and `e` are alike so 2/5 letters are alike,
`a` and `e`.

eg

```
val1 = "caffe"
val2 = "latte"
```

two inputs

and now output is "a" and "e"

Comment: What is your expected result for `bar` vs `or`?

Comment: just wants to print similar word !!

Comment: "caffe" and "latte" in this "a" and "e" are similar in both string

Comment: You can either implement or find a ready implementation of the [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) if you want to have a well-defined way to check string similarity.

Comment: What is your input? What is your expected output? Could you please formulate an example input which contains `caffe`, `latte`, `bar`, `or`? Please also `def` your desired function, leaving the body out.

Comment: It's very hard to understand what you need. To increase your chances of getting a meaningful answer, please write clearly, specify your input and output format very precisely and explicitly, give many input and output examples. Without these it's almost impossible for us to help you.

Comment: @pts `caffe` and `latte` this are two strings which i wants to compare and need to print similar characters ..

Comment: (As I asked earlier:) What is your expected output for `bar` vs `or`? If you care about getting an answer to your question, please help us clarifying what you want.

Comment: i just wants to print similar character in both strings!there is no "bar" or "or" in "caffe" or "latte"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to know the characters that are at the same position:

```
def alike(string, other)
  a = string.split(//)
  b = other.split(//)

  a.zip(b).map { |x, y| x if x == y }.compact
end

puts alike('latte', 'caffe')  # => [a, e]
puts alike('foo',   'bar')    # => []
```

If you want to get the number of matching positions:

```
def alike(string, other)
  a = string.split(//)
  b = other.split(//)

  a.zip(b).count { |x, y|  x == y }
end

puts alike('latte', 'caffe')  # => 2
puts alike('foo',   'bar')    # => 0
```

Comment: and what if i need n numbers of string to compare!!

Comment: Than you need to check every combination of two words anyway. But you did not tell in your question that you want to compare more than two words. Perhaps you should add that to your question...